# Luxury Plank Vinyl Flooring at a Beach Condo - Glue Down Vinyl vs Floating

Tags: flooring, installation, vinyl-flooring, vinyl

I am putting a new floor down in a beach condo, and I've been told by some that glue down LVP is best for the job, while other contractors are telling me that floating is better. This is a rental property that sees a lot of foot traffic/suitcases/sand/wet feet. Which would you all recommend: glue down or floating? Ideally I'd like the flooring to age well and last at least 5+ years if possible.

Thank you for any insight!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have been renting and remodeling properties for over 50 years, both long term and vacation rentals.

The best product that has come along in that 50 years is the floating LVP and LVT.

When installed properly it is almost bulletproof, ( of course not literally, but extremely durable.) and easy to clean.

It is easy to install. No expensive tools needed. Most brands are "score and snap". It doesn't need to acclimate to the interior conditions.
Glue down requires an absolutely smooth flat floor. Floating is more forgiving of imperfections.

Be sure to get a product that is at least 5mm thick.
The installation is critical.  If done properly the floor will give excellent protection against water intrusion.  If not there is no protection.

One of the things I do in my properties is "caulk for containment".

I caulk the baseboards to the floor. ( the flooring is always done before baseboards are installed.)  I also caulk the toe kicks in kitchen and baths to the floor.  The idea is to make it about impossible for water to get beyond the edges of the flooring. If done correctly, the floor will be waterproof.

I will add that I have installed flooring prior to installing cabinets. The manufacturers will tell you it should not be done.  I have done it and installed cabinets in kitchens and baths over the LVP with no ill results. The test of time has been good for at least 4 years now. However if you choose the same route it is on you.

Good luck

Comment: Trowing in unverifiable information does not improve the answer

Comment: You haven't explained _why_ it's best, and have just given an empty assertion. This is why opinion-based questions are off topic here.

Comment: Fixed that...just for you.

Comment: I don't think this question should have been closed. The answer by @RMDman is solid: explains the benefits of one over the other under the conditions the OP presented, and in terms of durability, water resistance, durability, and stresses the importance of a good installation, etc. If this is opinion-based, then *everything* on this site is opinion based.

Comment: i voted to reopen...tip of my hat to Cheery...amen brother.